# MS-ACCESS, JOIN SQL select

Tags: sql, join, max, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to build a Database Application in MS-ACCESS 2013. In this application I need a query that shows al Entries in NotificationsOfDelay joined with the last NotificationOfDelayStatus for that Item. Last means the biggest/latest timestamp. I've tried several googled SQL queries, but I just can't seem to get it right. Below my Code

```
SELECT tblNotificationOfDelay.ID,  tblNotificationOfDelayStatus.NotificationOfDelayID
FROM tblNotificationOfDelay 
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT TOP 1 tblNotificationOfDelayStatus.ID
FROM tblNotificationOfDelayStatus
WHERE tblNotificationOfDelayStatus.NotificationOfDelayID = tblNotificationOfDelay.ID
ORDER BY tblNotificationOfDelayStatus.TimeStamp DESC
);
```

Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: Instead of just trying google queries you should attempt to understand, what do you need and how to build query itself :) Hint - use grouping; `top 1` in joined query means joining to single record over entire query, which is not what you want.

Comment: You probably need a JOIN condition at the end. And let the subquery return NotificationOfDelayID  too.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT nod.ID,
       (SELECT TOP 1 nods.ID
        FROM tblNotificationOfDelayStatus as nods
        WHERE nods.NotificationOfDelayID = nod.ID
        ORDER BY nods.TimeStamp DESC
       )
FROM tblNotificationOfDelay as nod;
```

I'm not 100% sure that the correlation conditions are correct.  But a correlated subquery seems to be what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.